# How to install libschroedinger on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, unsupported-packages

I'm trying to compile `avconv` from source to work with ogg files. The issue that i'm having is that `libschroedinger` seems to be missing from repositories.

I have tried to look [in the package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libschroedinger&searchon=names) and it shows that package in 16.04, but not in the later versions. Has it been discontinued? Where can i find that library now?

Comment: By the way, depending on what exactly you mean by "work with ogg files", it's possible that you don't need it. I'd even say you probably don't; this library it to work on Dirac files, a pretty obscure video codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has been [removed from Debian](https://packages.qa.debian.org/s/schroedinger/news/20161220T060241Z.html), and thus from Ubuntu as well, due to "security issues" and lack of maintenance from developers.

Installing the 16.04 packages in 17.10 is likely to work. Otherwise, you can build it on 17.10 from the source package.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution for your problem is to use one of the distributions that has the library available e.g. trusty (14.04LTS) or xenial (16.04LTS), I recommend you xenial (16.04LTS) that is the last and newest version with that library you can still use, hope it helps.